# White screen after deleting a module

Tags: 8, database

I have a white screen "The website encountered an unexpected error.". The
"update.php" is not working.

I deleted a module that still was installed (big mistake).
I moved the module back into the folder. But has the white screen.
The watchdog table in SQL says that the used module is still missing.

Is there a chance to fix this?

Maybe in SQL? (I use Sequel Pro in place of myPHPadmin). 
Installing Drush seems to be complicated. I'm no programmer but a little experienced in coding with Drupal.

I looked many links online, but did not found the right solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deleted and returned a module to its original place, then all it takes for the website to start working normally again is to get cache refreshed, which will bootstrap it.

You can do it by:

1. Running the `update.php` file. Make sure to set `$settings['update_free_access'] = TRUE;` on the [settings.php](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/default/default.settings.php#n323) file.
2. Using `drush`. Installing drush is not as complicated as it might sound. Just follow instructions on http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install.
3. By clearing cache tables directly in the database. Just use some kind of user interface for the database like, for example, phpMyAdmin, open the website's database and truncate all the tables starting with `cache`.
4. If none of the above methods works, then try to uninstall and re-install the module or manually remove all database references to the fields which were created by the module.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I changed settings to TRUE, and Update.php did not work.
I cleared all caches, and Update.php did not work.

Then I followed the messages in "Watchdog". The module was not missed anymore. But further messages about 2 fields. I deleted in the "Config table" those two installed field entries. And "Update.php" and the website was working again. Those two fields were coming from the former deleted (but moved back again) module.

Comment: Mere deleting the modules files would not delete also involved fields. So that means you had uninstalled the module, which in fact triggers field removal commands in .install file. Thus your assertion `I deleted a module that still was installed (big mistake)` was misleading and knowing you had also removed the fields from the very beginning the answer would be slight different. Anyway, I am going to edit my answer taking into attention the newly provided facts and I hope you will accept my answer. Please do not leave your questions unanswered.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure anymore. The website was running after this.
But for sure things are more complicated. I had more warnings... and now white screen when I want to save a new node. I think I need a new clean installing.

Comment: I see. So will you accept my answer?

Comment: Of course sir. / What I did now... to fix the site. I had the error  [Mismatched entity and/or field definitions - a field needs to be uninstalled] (because I deleted it in SQL manually). / Drush I could not install successfully. The PHP entity update did not work (via index.php or devil php execute) - white screen. / Then I created in a content type a new text field with the same name from the missing field. / Now the entity update script worked. / Deleting the new field and no errors anymore.

Comment: I appreciate you saying "Of course", but you have to actually take action to accept my answer. I believe you just do not know how to accept an answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I understood you first time, but I was not able to follow. I looked around did not found how to do that. The gray icons on the left side did not look to me as any interactivity I have to use for your answer. Even second time I did not find out how to do that. Well after some minutes I found out.